# Qt: Session management error and Symbol lookup error in Centos 6.7

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, centos

I am newbie in centos and testing. My job is to test application created by my team. It is a Qt based application. Whenever i tried to launch it throws the two errors:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

./ExecutableName: symbol lookup error: ./Executable name: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii
```

I have installed most of the qt libraries. How can i rectify it ? 
(Note: It works fine in Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you recompile from source on Centos or did you use the same binaries as on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Executable you are trying to run is compiled with different major version of QT that is currently installed on the platform you try to run it.

Possible solutions:

- ensure that Qt's major versions match, eg. install appropriate qt version the executable was compiled with
- Ask for staticly compiled version
- compile the application yourself.